# How can I convert seconds to hours minutes and seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, time

How can I convert seconds into a custom `Time` struct?

```
struct Time
{
    public int hr;
    public int min;
    public int sec;
}
```

Is there a library function that can do this or do I have to implememt a function myself?

Comment: Use a `TimeSpan` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure.

```
TimeSpan myTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(9755);
Console.WriteLine("Hours: " + myTimeSpan.Hours); // 2
Console.WriteLine("Minutes: " + myTimeSpan.Minutes); // 42
Console.WriteLine("Seconds: " + myTimeSpan.Seconds); // 35
```

Verified with [random site](http://www.easysurf.cc/utime.htm#stohms) I found.

Comment: nice random site that you have found!!